# 0.%d range between 0-100 is the same as 100-1000

Tags: java, string.format

I have the command:

```
string.format("movel(p[0.%d,- 0.%d, 0.%d, -0.5121, -3.08, 0.0005])"+ "\n", averageX1, averageY1, averageY2 )
```

Where average value can change from 0 to 700. When the value is

```
averageX1 = 344
averageY1 = 222
averageY2 = 150
```

The command becomes:

```
movel(p[0.344,- 0.222, 0150, -0.5121, -3.08, 0.0005])
```

When one of the average becomes lower then 100:

```
averageX1 = 80
```

The command becomes

```
movel(p[0.**80**,- 0.222, 0150, -0.5121, -3.08, 0.0005])
```

I want it to become :

```
movel(p[0.**080**,- 0.222, 0150, -0.5121, -3.08, 0.0005]
```

How can I change this so it will have the value that can be from 0 tot 100.

ps. It is the "0" that must be in front of the "8".

kind regards
pascal

Comment: Change `0.%d` to `0.%03d`.  Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

Comment: This should be an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: Added a Community Wiki answer---feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `0.%d` to `0.%03d`. Also see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string).